# c# tcp radio application

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I have a tcp application
What i need to do is set up a few instances(done) and send commands to each server. I want that when given a specific command the server will listen to any action on the network and report the data, and still be able to send othe commands to this server or other ones.
My code:
radio instancese:

```
  instances = new radio1[list.Count];
                            for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                            {
                                instances[j] = new radio1(list[j].Key, list[j].Value);
                                // MessageBox.Show(instances[j].getIP());
                            }
```

sending commands

```
 while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            var splitinig = line.Split(',');

                            // MessageBox.Show(splitinig.Length.ToString());
                            for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
                            {
                              //  instances[i].sendCMD(listen);
                                if (splitinig[0] == instances[i].getRadio())
                                {
                                    if (splitinig[1].ToString() == "ptt1")
                                        instances[i].sendCMD(ptt1, splitinig[2].ToString());
                                    else if ((splitinig[1].ToString() == "ptt2"))
                                        instances[i].sendCMD(ptt2, splitinig[2].ToString());
                                    else
                                        instances[i].sendCMD(ptt0);
                                }
                            }

                            //MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
                        {
                            instances[i].sendCMD(stoplisten);
                            instances[i].closeConnection();
                        }
```

radio class sending command:

```
 public void sendCMD(string cmd)
        {

                //String str = ;
                Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(cmd);
                Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

                stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                /*   if (cmd == "$rmdbgvoicestats!")
                   {
                       bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent1);
                       //bTimer.Interval = 100;
                       bTimer.Enabled = true;
                   }*/

                while (tcpclnt.Connected)
                {
                    byte[] bb = new byte[tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        sb.Append((Convert.ToChar(bb[i])));
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    writeLog(cmd, sb.ToString());
                }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to cahnge this while loop to not interfere with the rest of the program? I want to listen to data while sending other commands in case no data is sent to me

Comment: I recommend going asynchronous :) [MSDN: Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with asynchronous ...Can you post an example?

Comment: There is one thing I don't follow there. ManualResetEvent named connectDone.??

Comment: Sending multiple commands to a server can result in problems.  A client is the master and the server is the slave.  A command should be sent to from the client to the server and then wait for a response.  The server code should always respond back to every message.  if you start sending multiple commands to the server without waiting for a response you may not know which response is being returned unless the server returns an id along with the response.

Comment: Create it as a field of your class like so: `private ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);`